# jquery ui multi date picker | select all the dates of month

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, jquery-multidatespicker

[image]

Library used: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

I want to select all the dates of a particular month when clicked on the month title.

Suppose I click on "January 2016", all the dates should be selected under January including the existing dates.

codepen link :-- http://codepen.io/hardiksh/pen/zqmgBw

i write below code :--

```
$( document .delegate( ".selectMonth", "click", function() {

var thisMonth = $(this).attr("data-month";
var thisYear = $(this).attr("data-year";

thisMonth = parseInt(thisMonth);
thisYear = parseInt(thisYear);

thisMonth = thisMonth +1;

lastDay = new Date(thisYear, thisMonth, 0).getDate();

if(thisMonth < 9){
    thisMonth = '0'+thisMonth;
}

allDates3 = [];

for (i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {

    if(i < 9){
        i = '0'+i;
    }

    allDates3.push(thisMonth+'/'+i+'/'+thisYear);
}



$('#full-year').multiDatesPicker('destroy');

$('#full-year').multiDatesPicker({
addDates: allDates3,
numberOfMonths: [3,4],
defaultDate: '1/1/'+y
});
});
```

Comment: Cool. Have you tried anything yet. People don't help you if you don't try something first.

Comment: i am modify multi date picker library and add checkbox every month and on click of that check box all days of month selected but on day extra selected.

Comment: What is `allDates3` outputting after the loop? When you do this `i = '0'+i;` you are turning `i` into a string, I'm not sure `i++` will work after that.

Comment: Output of allDates3 is all days of selected month

Comment: So if it has allDates of the selected month then what is your problem? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: All dates are selected but one extra dates selected with it

Comment: Extra selected date is randomly this date I don't want

Comment: If you can create a codeply or jsfiddle or some other example that we can debug I'll help further.

Comment: Ohk I will share codepan or jsfiddle link

Comment: i have share codepen click pls help me :-- http://codepen.io/hardiksh/pen/zqmgBw

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, maybe a bug in the picker or a setting/option that I can't figure out this removed it. I don't see why it's picking it.

```
$('#full-year').multiDatesPicker('destroy');
        $('#full-year').multiDatesPicker({
            addDates: allDates3,
            numberOfMonths: [3,4],
            defaultDate: '1/1/'+y
        });
    $('#full-year').multiDatesPicker('removeIndexes',0);
```

Comment: we remove from first index but some time date is selected randomly

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to figure it out either. I would make look at using a different plugin if you can.